# Converting Excel to PDF with VS2008 and Office2007

Tags: excel, pdf, interop

I am trying to use Interop.Excell to save an Excel Workbook as a PDF file. I am using VS2008 and Office2007, and have downloaded and installed the SaveAsPDFandXPS.exe from Microsoft. This enabled me to save a Word document as a pdf using the following code:
         object frmt = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;
         wrd.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(ref dest, ref frmt, ref unknown, ref unknown,...
Pretty cool excpet for the whole Interop thing.

Anyway, I have been unsucsessful in finding a parallel in Interop.Excell for the Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF. The Workbook.SaveAs takes a Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat, but there is no option for a pdf format. Has anyone done this or has experience in this area?

Answer (score 7):

This question has been answered here:

[**What is the FileType number for PDF in Excel 2007 that is needed to save a file as PDF through the API?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738829/what-is-the-filetype-number-for-pdf-in-excel-2007-that-is-needed-to-save-a-file-a)

You need to call the [`Workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238907.aspx) method:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF 
    FileName:=“sales.pdf” 
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard 
    DisplayFileAfterPublish:=True
```

This method should be preferred over using `SaveAs` because it also allows specifying all PDF / XPS options.

Note: This method has been added to the Excel object model with Excel 2007 and requires the [Save as PDF or XPS Add-in](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4d951911-3e7e-4ae6-b059-a2e79ed87041) for 2007 Microsoft Office programs (or SP2) to be installed.

Comment: For anyone else looking the full enums are `XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF` and `XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard`

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft, the constant to use with Workbook.SaveAs to save as a PDF is 57.

"The pdf format is not listed here. However it has number 57."
From:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241279%28office.12%29.aspx