# What is the FileType number for PDF in Excel 2007 that is needed to save a file as PDF through the API?

Tags: excel, pdf-generation, excel-2007, office-automation, excel-automation

I need to call a function in order to save an Excel workbook. I installed the PDF save addon for Excel 2007 but now I need to know what the number code is for the file format for when I save the excel file.

An example of the excel file format numbers can be found here.

http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/10/29/saveas-in-excel-2007/

```
FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
FileExtStr = ".csv": FileFormatNum = 6
FileExtStr = ".txt": FileFormatNum = -4158
FileExtStr = ".prn": FileFormatNum = 36
```

I need the one for the .pdf ending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this in Word, and the format number is 17.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [`Workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238907.aspx) method:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF 
    FileName:=“sales.pdf” 
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard 
    DisplayFileAfterPublish:=True
```

This method should be preferred over using `SaveAs` because it also allows specifying all PDF / XPS options.

Note: This method has been added to the Excel object model with Excel 2007 and requires the [Save as PDF or XPS Add-in](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4d951911-3e7e-4ae6-b059-a2e79ed87041) for 2007 Microsoft Office programs to be installed.

Comment: This was perfect. Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Excellent - though I found the last parameter to have another name `OpenAfterPublish`.