# Print Embedded Excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel, pdf

Edit:
I have a user control with embedded excel sheet  and gridviews ( WinForm). I have a form which has that user control. I have a print button on top and I want to convert the whole form into printable format. Any suggestion on how to move ahead?

Answer (score 0):

Printing an Excel document can be done using the [`Workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238907.aspx) method:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF 
    FileName:=“sales.pdf” 
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard 
    DisplayFileAfterPublish:=True
```

This method should be preferred over using `SaveAs` because it also allows specifying all PDF / XPS options.

Note: This method has been added to the Excel object model with Excel 2007 and requires the [Save as PDF or XPS Add-in](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4d951911-3e7e-4ae6-b059-a2e79ed87041) for 2007 Microsoft Office programs to be installed.

See this related question: [What is the FileType number for PDF in Excel 2007 that is needed to save a file as PDF through the API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738829/what-is-the-filetype-number-for-pdf-in-excel-2007-that-is-needed-to-save-a-file-a)

Comment: I want to print the excel worksheet and two other gridviews that are there in the user control all in a single click of button.

Answer (score 0):

For versions earlier than 2007 you can embed/install a PDF printer and use the `PrintOut` method, specifying `ActivePrinter` as required.