# Export Excel spreadsheet to PDF using OLE in Delphi XE3

Tags: excel, delphi, pdf, ole, delphi-xe3

Can anybody tell me how to export an excel spreadsheet to pdf using delphi code?

I know there is a command in the MS Word OLE object for exporting to PDf, but I cannot find anything about Excel.

Word To PDF Example:

```
Const
 wdExportFormatPDF = 17;

 WrdDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat(SaveToFile, wdExportFormatPDF);
```

Comment: @Tlama i dont want to be funny, but that makes no sense to me...

Comment: An example code would be much nicer:D

Comment: TLama is not being funny, your question was badly phrased: you were talking about Word *and* Excel. For an Excel object just use ExportAsFixedFormat as well http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb238907%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: i tried oSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat('C:\temp.pdf',xlTypePDF); but with no avail, i received an undeclared identifier error

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the FileType number for PDF in Excel 2007 that is needed to save a file as PDF through the API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738829/what-is-the-filetype-number-for-pdf-in-excel-2007-that-is-needed-to-save-a-file)

Comment: tried, didnt work @davidheffernan

Comment: -1 for saying "didn't work" with no more detail. You need to do better than that. Now, higher up you said that `xlTypePDF` leads to undeclared identifier. So go ahead and defined `xlTypePDF`! It has value 0: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb241296(v=office.12).aspx  All you need to do is read the error messages and do some websearch.

Comment: Sory, i mean i tried making sense of that post, but i could not. the correct answer was marked as 17, and i tried using the same const as i do with word as that page describes. But it says type miss match when i call WrdDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat('C:\temp.pdf', wdExportFormatPDF);

Comment: i defined it Const xlTypePDF=0; and then called
oSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat('C:\temp.pdf',xlTypePDF); and still got a type mismatch error @Davidheffernan

Comment: Well, what parameters does `ExportAsFixedFormat` expect? Don't be helpless in the face of compiler errors. Read them. It also never hurts to read the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb238907(v=office.12).aspx) You'd find that your parameters are the wrong way round. So, yes this question really is a dupe.

Comment: @davidheffernan You deserve a Gold star. You actually gave me links that i could use. thank you very much

Comment: browse through the links, his has explanations as to what needs to go where, and what the possibilities are for each of the options, as well as the const values for each

Comment: I think you just clicked the link I've provided and gave up even reading it. Never mind...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code is

```
wb.ExportAsFixedFormat(xlTypePDF, FileName);
```

or

```
sheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(xlTypePDF, FileName);
```

where `wb` is a workbook and `sheet` is a worksheet. If for some reason, your import library does not define `xlTypePDF`, it has value 0.

Some documentation links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198122.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840291.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb241296.aspx

If you read the documentation carefully you will discover that you have been passing the parameters in the wrong order.

Comment: where the hell do you guys find these links? i google my ass of and find nothing...

Comment: How do you think I got 247k rep? I'm not any good at programming, I'm just a wizard at websearch!!! ;-). And I'm only half joking. Seriously it just takes practise.

Comment: just 1 more thing, Do you know how to change the background color of a cell?Just the white space, i have tried finding a way, but excel doesnt have alot of help for me. @DavidHeffernan

Comment: I do know how to do that. But I can't answer in a comment here. At least not this instant.

Comment: @user2952034 Websearch gave me this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690924/set-excel-cell-backgroundcolor-from-c-sharp-winforms  and  http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/change-cell-background-color-using-vba-HA001136627.aspx  and http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10128  and  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840499.aspx