# Is XlFileFormat 57 still valid to save an Excel worksheet as PDF?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I want to Saveas an Excel worksheet as PDF format. I used XlFileFormat 57 before and it works well. But now it doesn't work and I found that it doesn't exist in the official web page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat . Anyone knows is it still valid or not ? Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for [`Worksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.exportasfixedformat) to save as pdf?

Comment: I am looking for Worksheet.SaveAs  to save as pdf.  [link(]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.saveas)

Comment: Try using `ExportAsFixedFormat`, that should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I don't want to change the code which works before unless it is confirmed obsoleted. Thanks anyway.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634990/converting-excel-to-pdf-with-vs2008-and-office2007

Comment: ^ Note, this question was answered in 2009. So yes, `ExportAsFixedFormat` is what you should use.